# loop breaks and gives an error as `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to loop through the JSON after executing the first row it start to read the `keys` inside the dict so I'm getting an error as ''str' object has no attribute 'get''

All I want is to get the next loop but it looping inside the dict.

When I print the `request.data` for the first time it prints the dict which is `{'AuditorId': 130, 'Agents': '', 'Supervisor': '', 'TicketId': '5354543', 'QId': 1, 'Answer': '2', 'SID': 7734, 'Comments': ''}`

After executing that it suppose got to next loop but its directly going inside the each loop n printing the `keys` when I print `request.data` in the console it get it as `ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId` which cause me the error

there is no issue in payload. But somewhere its going wrong I'm trying since yesterday any help would be appreciated

payload:

```
   [{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":42,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 
    
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":43,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""},  

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":44,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":45,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":46,"Answer":"3","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":47,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":48,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":49,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":50,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}]
```

views.py:

```
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 for ran in request.data:
            print('request.data--', ran)
            auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
            print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
            ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
            qid = ran.get('QId')
            answer = ran.get('Answer')
            # sid =  ran.get('SID')
            sid = '0'
            print('sid--', sid)
         
            qid = i['QId']
            print('qid--', qid)
            answer = i['Answer']
            print('answer--', answer)
       
            
               cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s',
                                        (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid))
               print(qid)
               result_st = cursor.fetchall()
               print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', result_st)
               for row in result_st:
                   print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', row)
               return Response(row[0])
```

Frontend where API Payload is getting created:

```
 this.service.SaveUserResponse(this.InputRequestList ).subscribe((response: Number) => {

          newsid = response;
          this.set = newsid;
        this.InputRequestList = [];

          var otcome: string = '';
       
          let supervisor = localStorage.getItem('PlusSupervisor');
          
          let Agent = localStorage.getItem('PlusAgent');
          
          let taskComments = localStorage.getItem('PlusText4')


          if (newsid != 0) {

            const inputRequest: UserResponse = {
              AuditorId: Number(localStorage.getItem("PlususerId")),
              Agents: (this.selectedAgent == undefined) ? '' : Agent,
              Supervisor: (this.selectedSupervisor == undefined) ? '' : supervisor,
              
             
              TicketId: this.ticket,
              QId: 0,
              Answer: this.selectedValue[i],
              SID: this.set,
              Comments: taskComments,

            }
```

[Here the payload load inside the list --1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh6Jh.png)
[Here is the browser payload--2 which comes in dict one by one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCApR.png)

Comment: Can you execute the command `print(type(request.data))`?

Comment: I have print(type(request.data)) `<class 'dict'>` @DavidLu  also I printed (type(ran)) its `<class 'str'>`

Comment: How could I loop it through the JSON without for loop is there any way. because of `ran` is causing the error.

Comment: Can you execute the command `print(request.data)`?

Comment: @DavidLu have printed I'm getting same payload  due to minimun character allowed I just pasted only 3 below `{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":42,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":43,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""},  
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":44,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""},{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":45,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""},

Comment: Its printing all the payload JSON @DavidLu

Comment: You uploaded as list but it received like dict? Did you upload correctly?

Comment: I have uploaded correctly, and  I have edited the payload as well now its completely dict only @DavidLu

Comment: So you mean, you didn't upload the data as a list?

Comment: I have uploaded the data as a list actually @DavidLu Data as a list of dicts

Comment: That's strange. Anyway, I posted my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Is `inputRequest` the payload?

Comment: yeah `inputRequest` is the payload

Comment: That is the object not list, right? But you wrote that the payload is the list of objects. Which one is correct?

Comment: I guess that's the object @DavidLu

Comment: So after all, did you upload just one object, not a list?

Comment: I changed my answer. You can just remove `many=True` from the serializer constructor in case when the payload is an object, not the list

Comment: still the same persist `{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list.', code='invalid')]}` and it return one after another

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of the browser payload @DavidLu pls check

Comment: Each response have dict which doesn't enclose in a list @DavidLu

Comment: Is this API method POST?

Comment: yes, API is POST method @DavidLu

Comment: I changed my answer. I forgot to remove the for loop when the request is the object type.

Comment: I meant, the last block is for the case of the object type.

Comment: Why do the two types of request payload exist? I think the either one is enough.

Comment: I finally changed my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Have tried but loops doesn't end it continuously going on in the loop @DavidLu

Comment: I think that is another problem in the function. And so I think I solved this issue. Could you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create the serializer to receive this data correctly.

```
class AuditorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    AuditorId = serializers.IntegerField()
    Agents = serializers.CharField(allow_blank = True)
    Supervisor = serializers.CharField(allow_blank = True)
    TicketId = serializers.CharField(allow_blank = True)
    QId = serializers.IntegerField()
    Answer = serializers.CharField(allow_blank = True)
    SID = serializers.CharField(allow_blank = True)
    Comments = serializers.CharField(allow_blank = True)
```

And in the views

```
serializer = AuditorSerializer(data = request.data, many = True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    input_data = serializer.validated_data
    if isinstance(input_data, list):
        for ran in input_data:
           process_data(ran)
    else:
        process_data(input_data)
else:
    print(serializer.errors)
    return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You can declare `process_data` function and pass the `ran` data, input the original code there.

Comment: I'm directly getting 400 bad request @David Lu

Comment: Can you show me the errors? I set the print command

Comment: The error is the most important. Because I think the payload is wrong somewhere.

Comment: I'm getting response as  bad request in the browser @David Lu

Comment: I meant, the log in the server side. I set the line `print(serializer.errors)` in my answer.

Comment: Error msg [{'Agents': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')], 'Supervisor': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')], 'Comments': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')]}, {'Agents': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may 
not be blank.', code='blank')], 'Supervisor': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')], @David Lu

Comment: Did you add the line `print(serializer.errors)` in your code?

Comment: Have added the errors but those fields are blank @David Lu

Comment: Okay I added the `blank=True` attribute in the `CharField`s. Please check it again.

Comment: getting type error as `super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'` in the serialiser after adding `blank = True`

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. it should be `allow_blank`, not `blank`. I changed my answer.

Comment: Error which I get is `{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "dict".', code='not_a_list')]}
{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "dict".', code='not_a_list')]}
{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "dict".', code='not_a_list')]}
{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "dict".', code='not_a_list')]}`

Comment: I think you uploaded data that is not a list type. Can you add the code that call the API into your post?

Comment: All I Just Create a API  I just get the payload response from the browser which comes from the frontend code. So u mean the payload have the issue is it?

Comment: Yeah, Can you add the frontend code that calls the Create API into your post?

Comment: Edited and Added the frontend code. Please have a look

Comment: tried the latest code which you provided got an error `{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list.', code='invalid')]}` @David Lu

Comment: Did you upload the list again?

Comment: added the screenshot where I will get the response in which have all the dicts in the list after that first response the following response just coming one by one as a dict  only not the list as u can see in the second screenshot @David Lu

Comment: Why is "one by one" needed after finishing "list" ?

Comment: its coming from the Payload which have each 'Qid' and 'Answer' response @David Lu